# Visual C++ Cross platform build failure

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

I just installed VS Community 2015 and after creating a OpenGLES application (Android/iOS) and building it, I've got an error message

```
1>------ Build started: Project: OpenGLESApp2.Android.Packaging, Configuration: Debug ARM ------
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
1>  ANT_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
1>  java.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91
1>  NDK_ROOT=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r11c\
1>  ANDROID_NDK_HOME=C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r11c\
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\MDD\Android\V140\Android.Common.targets(378,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\\bin\ant.bat" debug -Dout.final.file="C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\OpenGLESApp2\OpenGLESApp2\OpenGLESApp2.Android.Packaging\ARM\Debug\OpenGLESApp2.apk"" exited with code 3.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Also I noticed that there is no **bin** folder in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Apps\apache-ant-1.9.3\

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: What did you build? A simple "hello, world" app, or a full application?

Comment: @NonCreature0714 I am not sure about what you're asking but the exact name of the project template is called : "OpenGLES Application (Android/iOS) Visual C++". I haven't modified the source code which consists of a simple OpenGLES program that is supposed to display a cube I believe.

Comment: Ah, that answers my question, I wanted to know if you were just using the boiler plate code or not.

Comment: have you looked at https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/0.5/concepts/mobile-dev-setup-android-win/ ?

Comment: If you're missing the binary, that's likely the problem, you'll need to install Apache Ant (or reinstall). The link I provided is for Eclipse, but those are the general requirements for openGLES development.